# Keep newest x amount of files delete rest bash

Tags: linux, bash, debian

I have this this bash script as a crontab running every hour. I want to keep the latest 1,000 images in a folder, deleting the oldest files. I don't want to delete by mtime because if no new files are being uploaded, I want to keep them, it's fine to keep if image is 1 day or 50 days old, I just want when image 1,001 is uploaded (newest) image_1 (oldest) will be deleted, cycling through folder to keep a static amount of 1,000 images.

This works, However at ever hour, there could be now 1,200 by the time it executes. Running the crontab every say minute seems to be overkill. Can I make it so once the folder hits 1,001 images it auto executes? Basically I want the folder to be self-scanning and keep the newest 1,000 images, deleted the oldest one.

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /folder/to/execute; ls -t | sed -e '1,1000d' | xargs -d '\n' rm
```

Comment: What is the way that you follow in order to add new files ?

Comment: It's image uploading from users. It's for a chat, and when they upload it'll be uploaded as username_timestamp(.gif/jpg/png), which laravel php framework is doing the actual image uploading through chat. So it'll be random, could be 50 images a minute, or 50 images a day.

edit:
This script omits newest 1,000 files by timestamp, then just deletes anything left in the folder.

Comment: What about write some kind of webhook or a local script that checks the total count of images after uploading an image ? then when it hits 1000 trigger the shell command ? Will it be an overkill too ?

Comment: Well this is a local script. A webhook is a great idea. Do you have a suggestion of another local script? Basically per new image, a script runs to check the folder count and if over 1,000 run the script? Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
keep=10 #set this to how many files want to keep
discard=$(expr $keep - $(ls|wc -l))
if [ $discard -lt 0 ]; then
  ls -Bt|tail $discard|tr '\n' '\0'|xargs -0 printf "%b\0"|xargs -0 rm --
fi
```

This first calculates the number of files to delete, then safely passes them to `rm`. It uses negative numbers intentionally, since that conveniently works as the argument to `tail`.

The use of `tr` and `xargs -0` is to ensure that this works even if file names contain spaces. The `printf` bit is to handle file names containing newlines.

EDIT: added `--` to `rm` args to be safe if any of the files to be deleted start with a hyphen.

Comment: This works perfect, just in opposite order. It's keeping the 10 oldest files. But thank you! This answers my question. This is what I need, just now I need edited to keep newest files instead.

Comment: Can you show me how you got that result? I've tested it locally by reading the output and then by actually using it in a directory with 19 files created one second apart. It deleted the oldest files for me (as it should thanks to `tail`).

Comment: Sorry eric. I was using a script to generate files to test, and said script was generating so fast the timestamps were identical. Causing this confusion.

Comment: This works 100% and answers my question. Thank you very much. Marked as answered.

Comment: My first test script had the same timing problem. I had to add a sleep to the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following script.It first checks the count in the current directory and then , if the count is greater than 1000 , it evaluates the difference and then gets the oldest such files.

```
    #/bin/bash
    count=`ls -1 | wc -l`
    if [ $count -gt 1000 ]
    then
     difference=${count-1000}
     dirnames=`ls -t * | tail -n $difference`
     arr=($dirnames)
     for i in "${arr[@]}"
      do
         echo $i
      done
    fi
```

Comment: Am I doing something wrong? I created 2,000 text files, and ran the bash script. It just outputs a file "1000" and lists each file in bash like running cat. http://i.imgur.com/McuD6vY.png

I tried with 1,500 to make sure it wasn't something on my end, same results. http://i.imgur.com/FxrqXHZ.png

Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: If I am getting it correctly , you want the files which were created older than the latest 1000 files?

Comment: I would like to scan the folder, if there is over 1,000 files, delete the older files first, until there is only 1,000 left. Keeping the newest 1,000 files.

Comment: Yeah right , so what this script does is lists all the oldest files without the latest 1000 files.Try one thins, create 3~4 files in a directory , change the parameter `1000` to`2` in the script every where , and then run the script there , It should print the older files excluding the latest 2 files.

Comment: convert `>` to `-gt` for numeric compare